# What does a higher clock signal frequency actually mean for my AHRS?

Tags: arduino-uno, accelerometer, gyroscope, frequency

I've got an Arduino with an ATmega328 processor. It can be operated at 3.3V which nets a clock signal frequency of about 12 MHz respectively 16 Mhz at 5V.

I've got an IMU connected to the Arduino and a AHRS algorithm turning accelerometer, gyroscope and magnetometer data into orientation data.

What does the higher frequency of 16 MHz actually mean in this context?

Will the AHRS be calculated faster so I get a lower latency? Can I poll the sensors more often? I want a deeper understanding of what I'm doing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does the higher frequency of 16 MHz actually mean in this context?

The Arduino will run a bit faster (33% faster). Therefore it could calculate things faster. Whether you can poll the sensors more often might depend on the sensor. Limiting factors could be how fast you can communicate with the sensor, how often the sensor takes readings, what you are going to do with the readings, and whether it matters if calculations are a bit slower.

For a better response I suggest you post a link to the particular sensor, the AHRS algorithm you are using, and describe the application you are using it for.

Comment: Thanks Nick, this was just about making sure that I "get it". I'm already satisfied with how my AHRS performs. I'm interested in improving the latency of my system but there are worse bottlenecks like the serial communication via Bluetooth, how fast my node.js middleware processes it, how fast that communicates with the actual application I'm using it in.